# M4: Is it possible to divert to a file from withing an .m4 file?

Tags: macros, gnu, preprocessor, m4

I just want to know if it is possible for m4 to divert to a specific file instead of shell redirection on the command line.

So, something like this:

```
divert(`path/to/file.result')
This text is written to path/to/file.result
divert
This text appears on stdout
```

I could figure out how to do this from the shell, I am just wondering if there is such a thing in m4.

Thanks for any answers.

Comment: According to the GNU M4 manual, this is not possible. `divert` only writes to memory or, if memory is used up, to a temporary file. Interestingly, you could 'undivert' from a file: _GNU m4 allows named files to be undiverted. Given a non-numeric argument, the contents of the file named will be copied, uninterpreted, to the current output. This complements the builtin include (see Include)._

Comment: I was afraid so, I looked at the manual extensively and found I can basically only do something like this ```syscmd(`cat <<EOF > file'
`some contents'
EOF')
```
And define that as a macro.